# For STM32 devices, How is SCLH and SCLL calculated in I2C_TIMINGR?

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32cubeide

I have read the document RM0433 and AN4235, but the calculation is still a puzzle.

For example, if my

I2C frequency = 1MHz,

I2C clock source frequency = 170MHz,

AF=on, DF=off,

rise time = 80ns,

fail time = 10ns,

how do you get the SCLH = 0x10 and SCLL = 0x31?

Why is low period 3 times as long as high period?

I would like to use SCLH to increase the high clock period, as it is at the edge of the spec. It is not clear what parameter I shall change to increase SCLH.

Thanks.

Comment: Remember that SCL has to be stable low before you can change SDA, and SDA has to be stable before you can let SCL go high again.  I don't think an I2C clock source of 170MHz is allowed.  Are you sure about that?

Comment: @TimRoberts, yes, that is SDADEL and SCLDEL :) why do you think 170MHz is not allowed as I2C clock source? I used it and it did not seem to cause any trouble. Would like to know why :)

Comment: I may not have read deep enough.  I thought you were limited to 48MHz or 72MHz, depending on the chip.  If there are enough divisors, then I suppose it's fine.